# How to add an array item to a new view according to a selected option in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a React project where a list of books will be retrieved from the server.Each book has an option to be set into different shelves, like 1) Currently reading, 2) Want to read and 3) Read based on the user's experience with the book.Each book will have a dropdown where the 3 shelves will be mentioned.Once the user clicks on a shelf from the dropdown,the book will be shown on the selected shelf.So, I am able to retrieve the books from the API, but I am stuck at the point where the books will be set to the respective shelf once it is selected.

Code to retrieve all the books from the API:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class BooksList extends Component {

  state={
    showSearchPage: false,
    books: [],
    selectedValue: 'None'
  }

  handleChange =(e) => {
    this.setState({ selectedValue:e.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return(
{<div className="book-search">
                  {this.props.books.map( book =>

                    <div className="book">
                      <div className="book-top">
                        <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193,margin:10, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail})` }}></div>
                        <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                          <select
                            value={this.state.selectedValue}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}>
                            <option value="none" disabled>&nbsp; &nbsp; Move to...</option>
                            <option value="currentlyReading">&#x2714; Currently Reading</option>
                            <option value="wantToRead">&nbsp; &nbsp; Want to Read</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="read">&nbsp; &nbsp; Read</option>
                            <option value="none">&nbsp; &nbsp; None</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="book-title">{book.title}</div>
                      <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
                      <p>{this.state.selectedValue}</p>
                    </div>
              )}
              </div>
                }
```

Code for the Currently Reading shelf:

```
<div className="list-books-content">
                <div>
                  <div className="bookshelf">
                    <h2 className="bookshelf-title">Currently Reading</h2>
                    <div className="bookshelf-books">
                      <ol className="books-grid">


                        { this.props.books.map(book =>
                          <li>
                            <div className="book">
                              <div className="book-top">
                                <div className="book-cover" style={{ width: 128, height: 193, backgroundImage: `url(${book.imageLinks.smallThumbnail})` }}></div>
                                <div className="book-shelf-changer">
                                  <select
                                    value={this.state.selectedValue}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                    <option value="none" disabled>&nbsp; &nbsp; Move to...</option>
                                    <option value="currentlyReading">&#x2714; Currently Reading</option>
                                    <option value="wantToRead">&nbsp; &nbsp; Want to Read</option>
                                    <option selected="selected" value="read">&nbsp; &nbsp; Read</option>
                                    <option value="none">&nbsp; &nbsp; None</option>
                                  </select>
                                  <p>{this.state.selectedValue}</p>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div className="book-title">{this.state.currentlyReadingBooks}</div>
                              <div className="book-authors">{book.authors}</div>
                            </div>
                            </li>
                        )}
```

So what I was thinking of as a solution is : Do we have to create 3 arrays of books for three different sections and move the books to each section.Can anyone please help me with this.I am really stuck with this.I am not able to figure out how to proceed.

Comment: Where is the API call ? What is the content of `this.props.books` ?

Comment: One option is to have 3 arrays of books. On select you put the book in respective array. In render you render three arrays separately (or even better: render 3 components and pass them the respective array). The other option is to have array of book OBJECTS, and add an attribute to each book object where it belongs. Then in render you can filter by this attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Once the user clicks on a shelf from the dropdown,the book will be shown on the selected shelf

This tells me that you probably don't need to store `selectedValue` in the react state; as soon as a dropdown action action is selected, simply "add" it.

So yes, I think what you describe makes sense - have three seperate arrays of books stored in the react state, and then in your `handleChange` function, append the book to the appropriate array.

(Side note: best practice in react is to copy the only array from your state instead of directly appending/mutating it.)

Comment: how do I append the selected book to the new state in handleChange function?